# Не получается сделать функцию подсчета столбцов в sqlite. RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть таблица sqlite.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу посчитать сумму столбцов agent_materials в таблице profile. Написал такой код:

```
def all_agent_materials():
    cur.execute('SELECT SUM(agent_materials) as sum FROM profile')
    print({all_agent_materials()})
    db.commit()
```

Выдаёт ошибку «RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison»
Написал тот же код, только в самом sql - все работает. Что не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит из-за того что код зациклен, но я не понимаю что нужно сделать чтобы это профиксить.
Пробовал поднять max recursion, но пайтон просто крашится.

Comment: Print вытащите из функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы внутри функции `all_agent_materials` снова вызываете функцию `all_agent_materials` (в аргументах `print`), отсюда и рекурсия, и базы у нее нет, поэтому всегда будет возникать переполнение.

В `sqlite` все это делается через курсор, у вас приведен очень маленький фрагмент кода, но по переменной `cur` я полагаю, что вы, все-таки, его используете.

Для решения вашей проблемы вместо еще одного вызова функции требуется вызвать метод `fetchall` у курсора, который возвращает все строки, полученные в результате запроса в виде списка.

Суть примерно такая:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("table.db")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT SUM(agent_materials) as sum FROM profile')

result = c.fetchall()

print(result)
```

**Дополнительно**

Делать коммит `db.commit()` в данном случае смысла никакого нет, поскольку чтение данных не изменяет таблицу и, поэтому, подтверждать нечего (если помимо запроса `SELECT` у вас не выполняется никаких иных операций).